# How to limit the upload speed of an application?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

I am using QNetworkAccessManager to upload a file (and some data) like this:

```
QNetworkRequest request(<some URL>);
QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
<multipart is filled with single parts>

networkAccessManager->post(request, multiPart);
```

It works well.
However, users have reported that the upload influences their upload bandwidth. Which... makes sense, of course ;)

Now, I would like to implement something to limit the upload speed of this post request. However, after looking around for a while, I found absolutely nothing to do this in any simple way.

There is setReadBufferSize for the QNetworkReply, but no equivalent for writing. Seems like an obvious mistake not to add that...

I have found this thing: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-torrent-example.html
And tried to adjust some of its classes to my needs.
However, it all fails because I just cannot find a way to interrupt the writing of data (to do it slower than it normally would). That example relies on the user writing the writing-code himself - but that isn't possible here since Qt internally does the writing of the data after a post request.

I also tried using the Windows API Traffic Control, but that can just be used to limit a complete network interface or inspect packets, not a specific application. Plus, this has practically no examples, just some ancient code snippets. Not exactly what I want to work with...

Is there any way to achieve an upload throttle at all without having to rewrite Qt sources (which I won't do)?
A way to "globally" limit the upload speed of the application would be acceptable as well, using Windows API code or anything, really, as long as it is possible in code.

**Additional info:**
Limiting the upload speed of the user's computer is **not** acceptable. It must be limiting only a specific application. Similar to what you can do with NetLimiter.

Comment: I'd imagine that NetLimiter does this at a low level, probably by installing a driver. Are you prepared to do that.

Comment: Are there many POST requests or just one? Depending on the answer we may try to delay requests for limiting the download speed.

Comment: David: That does sound like a lot of work (especially since I need it just for one application, our own). I think if it would come to that, it would actually be easier to just use a timed socket connection in Qt and do all of the HTTP stuff manually. Would also be a lot of work, but at least simpler ;)  

@AlexanderVX This POST request can happen many times. But only once at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I would try this way: `QHttpMultiPart` uses `QHttpPart` elements as data chunks. And `QHttpPart` has `QHttpPart::setBodyDevice( QIODevice * device )` to set its data provider. Create your own `QIODevice` provider and control data bandwidth inside it.

**EDIT:**
More general solution for `QNetworkAccessManager` would be to provide `QIODevice` for `QNetworkAccessManager::post( const QNetworkRequest & request, QIODevice * data )` and control the bandwidth there.

See also at [this proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/730163/686530)

Comment: That is an interesting idea, it might just work. However, since this approach has taken too long, we just went an implemented libcurl in the meantime, replacing QT's down/upload functionality entirely at least for the parts where we need it. Meaning I cannot really test this at the moment. Additionally, I'm not sure if I should accept this, since it is very specific to QHttpMultiPart, while I was looking more for a general (or at least for QNetworkAccessManager) solution. Maybe there simply is no solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

While not a 100% solution for this problem (it's not using Qt and not limiting an application's bandwidth in general, so I won't "accept" this), this is the workaround we ended up implementing:

A class that makes use of
[libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se)

We are using that class instead of a QNetworkAccessManager wherever we need to have an up/download with a speed limit.

Built libcurl myself with OpenSSL support, and then you can very easily use the [CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_MAX_SEND_SPEED_LARGE.html) parameter to set the upload speed limit.